# What is the fastest way to overwrite a file?

Tags: c#, file, copy

I know this sounds very trivial, but I have a very specific reason for asking.

I'm reaching across a very crappy network to Mumbai, India. If I were local, I would simply run this code below:

```
                if (File.Exists(f2))
                {
                    File.Delete(f2);
                }

                File.Copy(f1, f2);
```

Of course, I have to test to see if the file exists first, because I can't just copy the file over the top of an existing file. C# complains about that. Here's the problem.. The "Test to see if it exists first" takes 5 seconds alone. Then the delete takes about 3. And finally, the copy takes about 15. For a fifteen second copy, it ends up taking 23 seconds.

That's an increase of 8 seconds, or about 50% overhead, just to prevent a C# error.

Is there any way to say

```
File.Copy(f1, f2, Just_do_it_damnit)
```

... without all of the "does it exist" overhead?

Comment: You don't need to check to see if the flie exists. You can just attempt to delete it and catch the exception if it doesn't.

Comment: The fastest way to overwrite a file is ... [read this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`File.Copy(f1, f2, true)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx) to overwrite the destination file.

Comment: Duh.. I need more sleep. I knew that.. Really.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, what's wrong with just using this?

```
File.Copy(f1,f2,true);
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean

```
File.Copy(f1, f2, True)
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the question.

```
File.Copy(f1, f2, true);
```

See Microsoft's page about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa328774%28v=VS.71%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

File.Copy has third parameter -- a boolean flag which specifies if should overwrite if the file already exists. So I would think File.Copy(f1, f2, true) so do what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9706cfs5(v=VS.80).aspx